# How to trigger click event on uploadify

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I would like to trigger the click event on uploadify v3 (to be able to style my file form), tried something like this :

html

```
 <div class="input-append" >
            <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="files"  >
            <input placeholder="Click here to browse files..." id="appendedInputButton" class="addfilefp" type="text">
            <button class="btn addfilefp" type="button">BROWSE</button>
        </div>
```

and javascript

```
$('.addfilefp').change(function(){
$('#files').focus().trigger('click');

return false;
})
$('#files').uploadify({

    'auto' : false,
    'method'   : 'post',
    'fileSizeLimit' : '100MB',
    'multi'    : true,
    'queueSizeLimit' : 10,
     ................
```

css (the file form is visible and out of screen):

```
#files {
position:absolute; left: -9999px;
 }
```

but the click wont trigger (as far as i know this is a security issue), any workaround ??

Thanks

Comment: can you provide http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry, I can't include flash to jsfiddle